# How to set-up Mongo replica set on Kubernetes?

Tags: mongodb, docker, kubernetes

I'm trying set-up a three node Mongo replica set on Kubernetes. My thoughts is start three pods, with Mongo in each one, when the pod starts, it automatically sets up the replica set, so I need to modify the Mongo image Dockerfile to execute some command in Mongo shell.
But I am stuck at executing the command `rs.initiate()`. If I just use the command `rs.initiate()` without parameters it works, but when adding parameters then it occurs error like

```
rs.initiate({ "_id": "rs0", "members" : [ { "_id" : 0, "host" : "172.18.248.87:27017" } ]})
```

But when executing the pod and using the same command with parameters, it works. The same situation with the command  `rs.add()` . How to resolve this?

Plus: in my Dockerfile I use `mongo  admin --port 27017 --eval  "rs.initiate()"` to execute the command .

Answer (score 0):

You should check hosts file (hostname) in pod and add :

> ip_address  mongoslave
>
> ip_address mongomaster

For example :

> 172.18.248.87 mongomaster

Then you add parametters:

> rs.initiate()
>
> rsconf = {
>              _id: "rs0",
>              members: [
>                         {
>                          _id: 0,
>                          host: "mongomaster:27017"
>                         }
>                       ]
>            }
>
> rs.reconfig(rsconf, {force: true})